# Java recursion not iterating all top level elements

Tags: java, recursion

I am facing a problem with recursion. I have an object which holds a list of itself and each of those objects in the list can hold a list itself. This object represents a tree.

Now I want to iterate all the possible objects to find 1 specific object, but I am failing at it. Currently my method does not return to the top levels and I have no idea how to fix it.

Method:

```
private Object selectSpecificItem(TreeObject treeObject) {
    for (TreeObject to : treeObject.getChildren()) {
        Object data = to.getData();
        if (data instanceof PaymentOffice) {
            PaymentOffice po = (PaymentOffice) data;
            if (po.getCode().equals(getModelObject().getLocation())) {
                return to;
            }
        } else if (to.getChildren().length > 0) {
            selectSpecificItem(to);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Assume following list structure:

```
Item1
    - Item1.1
    - Item1.2
    - Item1.3
    - Item1.4
Item2
Item3
```

Right now it iterates over all 1/1.x items but not 2/3. And the item I need to find right now is `Item3`

**How do I have to change the recursion to iterate all elements?**

Comment: you probably want to change `selectSpecificItem(to);` to `return selectSpecificItem(to);` in your else if

Comment: @Lino I already tried that too, but nothing changed

Comment: Do you have any root **TreeObject**  which will hold **Item1, Item2. Item3** as its children?

Comment: @NisheshPratap Yes, it is passed in as first call

Comment: Well you're not iterating over the other 2 items, because in the first one you're returning already something

Comment: You never check if `treeObject` holds a PaymentOffice, just it's children.

Comment: @Tibrogargan because I do know that I pass it in as parent and that the root does not have any data

Comment: Ok, might want to consider making the root a different class, since it has different behavior.  Or maybe implementing your search as: if (this.data matches search) { return this } else { recurse to children }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are ignoring the value returned by the recursive call. You should check whether the recursive call returned a non `null` value, and if it did, return it.

```
private Object selectSpecificItem(TreeObject treeObject) {
    Object result = null;
    for (TreeObject to : treeObject.getChildren()) {
        Object data = to.getData();
        if (data instanceof PaymentOffice) {
            PaymentOffice po = (PaymentOffice) data;
            if (po.getCode().equals(getModelObject().getLocation())) {
                return to;
            }
        } else if (to.getChildren().length > 0) {
            result = selectSpecificItem(to);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Some people like to have a single `return` statement at the end of the method. If you are such a person, you can write:

```
private Object selectSpecificItem(TreeObject treeObject) {
    Object result = null;
    for (TreeObject to : treeObject.getChildren()) {
        Object data = to.getData();
        if (data instanceof PaymentOffice) {
            PaymentOffice po = (PaymentOffice) data;
            if (po.getCode().equals(getModelObject().getLocation())) {
                result = to;
                break;
            }
        } else if (to.getChildren().length > 0) {
            result = selectSpecificItem(to);
            if (result != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you could also `break` out the for loop instead of returning the `result` in the else if, which would be the same

Comment: @Lino that's true

Comment: Thank you very much. It does return the right element now